# IDispose is neccessary, does Garbage collector work at end of loops etc

Tags: vb.net, garbage-collection, idisposable

My question is about IDisposable implementation. To my knowledge, when a code or section is complete, the variable or instance is disposed; please correct me if the statement is wrong.  The follow is part of my program:

```
 If Con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then Con.Open()
        Cmd = New SqlCeCommand("Select * from BillItem", Con)
        Rdr = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While Rdr.Read = True
            Dim x As New Classes.StockRoster
            x.BillID = Rdr("BillID")
            x.IsSales = Rdr("IsSales")
            x.Quantity = Rdr("Quantity")
            x.ContactBase = (From t As CommonCodes.ItemBase In ContactsbaseDict Where t.ID = BillContactDict(x.BillID)).First
            x.StockEntityBase = StockEntitydict(Rdr("StockID"))
            x.BillDate = Rdr("BillDate")
            result.AddRange(x)
        End While
        Con.Close()
 End IF
```

In case of X variable here, would there be any memory improvement if I x (or StockRoster) would use IDisposable interface?

Couldn't the resources get disposed by default at end of each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IDisposable` is about disposing unmanaged resources such as a database connection. It doesn't have anything to do with the garbage collection.

Your `StockRoster` class doesn't seem to hold unmanaged resources so it doesn't need to implement `IDisposable`. Even if it did, it wouldn't make sense to dispose it in your `for` loop, because you add the instance to the result list that you will later use. Disposing it in the `for` loop would make the instance unusable in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you would never enter the `If-clause` if the connection is open what could happen f.e. in case of an exception.

Actually the connection is the best example. Always close connections as soon as possible. The easiest way is to use `using-statement` which calls `Dispose` at the end (even in case of an exception). So it's similar to a `Try/Catch/Finally`. `Connection.Dispose` will also close it implicitely.

As a rule of thumb: use the `using-statement` for anything implementing `IDisposable` (like the `SqlCeCommand` above).

To answer you actual question:

> would there be any memory improvement if I x (or StockRoster) would
>   use IDispose class, couldn't the resources get dispose by default at
>   end of each loop?

What is *memory improvement*, `IDisposable` is an interface, you could call dispose or close even when the class doesn't implement `IDisposable`. That's just a hint  that it probably uses unmanaged resources and should be disposed as soon as possible.